# Are widgets that have bound commands disabled when hidden

Tags: python, tkinter

Say I have a widget that has a function bound to the enter key:

```
Def some_func():
    Print("hi")

Entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
Entry_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
Entry_1.bind("<Return>", some_func)
```

If I were to "Entry_1.grid_forget" this entry to (for example) replace it with another widget that is bound to the enter key, would there be any interference from the "removed widget"?

Comment: Have you tried this out? Have you experienced any "interference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the widget is hidden or not, key bindings are active whenever the widget has keyboard focus. Only one widget at a time can have keyboard focus.